# PHP Alert text customise

Tags: php

[A CRUD project, Delete warning alert showing **localhost says** I want to remove this one, The alert will only show the alert text. Is it possible?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYf7U.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot edit this. This comes with the browser you use.
But you can use a custom alert instead! I would recommend using SweetAlerts2. Here's the link, they are a documentation with examples so you should get the idea of it pretty quickly. Happy coding!

https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: very nice and thanks a lot but how i can use it here

``document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 console.log('loaded');

 var links = document.querySelectorAll(".delete");
 for(i=0; i<links.length;i++){
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
   if(!confirm("Are You Sure?")){
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  });
 }
});``

Comment: Use swal.fire inside the DOMContentLoaded function. Define the icon, text etc. Then you can use. `.then((result) =>` to run what you want it to do if the user clicks ok or confirm.